# Cannot connect to internet or even ping from "Bash on ubuntu on Windows"

Tags: networking, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Unable to ping or download any packages.   Below are the contents of resolv.conf

```
root@LAPTOP-UQSGIHE1:/mnt/c/# cat /etc/resolv.conf
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 192.168.100.1    
nameserver 202.148.200.3    
nameserver 202.148.202.4
```

```
oracle@LAPTOP-UQSGIHE1:/mnt/c/Windows/System32$ sudo ifconfig
sudo: unable to resolve host LAPTOP-UQSGIHE1
Warning: cannot open /proc
/net/dev (No such file or directory). Limited output.
```

Comment: What does `ip addr` command show? And please, use [markdown to format](http://askubuntu.com/editing-help) the question.

Comment: oracle@LAPTOP-UQSGIHE1:~$ ip addr

**SO_SNDBUF: Invalid argument**

Comment: Hmm… Does `ifconfig` throws errors too? And btw, it's important information which you better off include into the question than leave in comments.

Comment: oracle@LAPTOP-UQSGIHE1:/mnt/c/Windows/System32$ sudo ifconfig                                  


sudo: unable to resolve host LAPTOP-UQSGIHE1                                                                                                       

Warning: cannot open /proc/net/dev (No such file or directory). Limited output.

Answer (score 3):

The problem you're having is because Microsoft still develops *bash on Windows*, and the network capabilities on Windows 10 are not fully implemented yet.

Though it was widely believed that it is implemented to more or less usable state, so of course there's a bug report. You can track [the progress of solving the bug here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/69), be sure to read comments of *sunlimit* user, they is a Microsoft employee, and explains the problem.

I'd recommend to make some kind of activity there — the more peoples interested, the faster it get fixed.

Comment: Here's the link for voting for the issue directly on the Windows Developer Feedback page: https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/266908-command-prompt-console-bash-on-ubuntu-on-windo/suggestions/15202875-would-you-like-to-support-ifconfig-iw-iwconfig-t

Answer (score 3):

To solve the "unable to resolve host", do this

```
sudo rm /etc/hosts
```

close the window and run bash again to regenerate hosts file.

Comment: It is not working for me. I removed the /etc/hosts and reopened bash.